# Js click function that copies a divs class on click and stores it as a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, events

Still need help.

I'm looking to set up a click function that sniffs for the divs class that's clicked and stores it as a variable. To than use that variable to toggle slideDown the relative div.

JS

```
var $clickedOn = ...;

$( ".color" ).click(function() {
  $('.information').slideUp('slow');
  $( ".(clickedOn).tuckinfo" ).slideDown('slow');
});
```

HTML

This is what is being clicked.

```
<div class="color-list">
  <div class="container">
    <section class="color hospitality">
```

This is what I want to drop down when clicked.

```
<div class="greybg tuckinfo">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="hospitality-extended">
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/alcoven/pen/pvKzwd)

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJjYW.gif
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnRr2.jpg

Comment: So... what's your specific question now?

Comment: Any clicked div? Only those inside some element? Please clarify. Also, the click function you've included here seems irrelevant.

Comment: It's called `this`, and what you probably want is `$(this)`

Comment: Oh, I see. You're going about this all wrong. Use `closest()` and `find()` to target the toggled element, not a class.

Comment: I don't know what to put in the var area. I want only the other class from the div .color I.E <div class="color hospitality"> I want just the hospitality and than I want to copy that and use it as $(('variable'+-expanded).tuckinfo).slideDown('slow'); so .hospitality-expanded .tuckinfo would be the selector to drop down. Not sure what the syntax for something like this would be.

Comment: Please update your question with a snippet of HTML that shows the relationship between `.color.hospitality` and the element you're toggling. There's a much better way to do this.

Comment: I asked for a relationship structure, not two random, detached elements. :-)

Comment: not sure what you mean by that. @isherwood

Comment: Show that smallest continuous block of HTML that shows both of those elements in their native locations.

Comment: I updated, but if what you're looking for isn't in the post I've attached a codepen url

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `class` attribute. `this` contains the element that was clicked on

```
$( ".color" ).click(function() 
{
  var className = '.' + $(this).attr('class').replace('color','').split(/\s+/).join('.');
  $('.information').slideUp('slow');
  $( ".greybg.tuckinfo .container " + className + '-expanded').slideDown('slow');
});
```

Comment: While this answers the question, it's very fragile. What if the clicked element has multiple classes, perhaps added by a plugin?

Comment: hmmm. good point @isherwood I still need -expanded added to the string though. this is close!

Comment: I just modified it to support multiple CSS classes. Thanks isherwood.

Comment: The problem is not handling multiple classes--it's that the target element won't have the same classes itself.

Comment: It still won't add -expanded to the end of the string. Thanks for you help @imelgrat

Comment: How's the target class? hospitality-expanded? If that's the case, you can remove the "color" class and and -expanded to the remaining class

Comment: looks like it would work, but after pasting it I'm still not getting the right result.

Comment: Fixed a tiny mistake. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your markup, and I'm going to take a stab at a fuller solution.

The solution was to add data attributes to the elements from which you want to trigger the slide up/down, and then corresponding data attributes for the elements that will be affected.

```
<div data-trigger-action="set1">Click Me</div>

<div data-trigger-key="set1">Slide me 'round</div>
```

Then in your JS:

```
$("[data-trigger-action]").on("click", function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

  var _key = $(this).attr("data-trigger-action");

  $triggerKeys
    .filter('[data-trigger-key!="' + _key + '"]').slideUp()
    .end().filter('[data-trigger-key="' + _key + '"]').slideDown();
});
```

See [this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emKdrv) for a working example.

(Note: I may have misidentified the items you want to affect, so moving the [data-trigger-key] attributes around should resolve that.)

**EDIT**

Here's the updated JS code, which would use your original HTML:

```
  // configure some action keys and selectors for elements to apply them to
  var keysToApply = {
    /* 'key/value to share': ['jquery-selector-to-action-el', 'jquery-selector-to-target-el'] */
    'hospitality': ['.color-list .color.hospitality', '.greybg.tuckinfo'],
    'taverns': ['.color-list .color.taverns', '#wrapper .information']
  };

  // loop through our config and apply the data attributes
  $.each(keysToApply, function(key, params)
  {
    $(params[0]).attr('data-trigger-action', key);
    $(params[1]).attr('data-trigger-key', key);
  })

  // cache our jQuery objects for our actions/keys
  var $triggerActions = $('[data-trigger-action]'),
      $triggerKeys = $('[data-trigger-key]');

  // handle the sliding up/down of items on click
  $("[data-trigger-action]").on("click", function(e)
  {
    e.preventDefault();

    var _key = $(this).attr("data-trigger-action");

    $triggerKeys
      .filter('[data-trigger-key!="' + _key + '"]').slideUp()
      .end().filter('[data-trigger-key="' + _key + '"]').slideDown();
  });
```

Comment: This solution is great! Just worried about implementing into wordpress due to having to change the markup. I probably should have specified.

Comment: @Aaron Ah, good 'ole WordPress. Well, you've got three options: (1) edit the template file from the theme; (2) have more lines of JS code to target each trigger/affected element separately; (3) have some initializing JS code to apply the data attributes before attaching the click event. Out of those three crummy options, I'd opt for #3. If you do as well, I'll modify the codepen for you.

Comment: @Aaron Alrighty, the codepen has been updated. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you, I applied the js form your codepen and made a few more hidden divs. When I click on taverns hospitality stays open though, and vise versa.

Comment: Make sure the selectors (the second value in the array of items inside keysToApply) are correctly identifying the elements you want to affect. I just took a stab at it based on what I could decipher from the markup. Perhaps I had the selectors swapped - is this right? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KweNwa

Comment: Same thing is happening. Idealy one of those hidden sections would slide up when clicked. and all others would remain hidden. I've also added all divs now, so we can test. http://codepen.io/alcoven/pen/pvKzwd

Comment: @Aaron Do this: make the elements you want to be toggled contain only a number, so it will be easy to talk in the same terms (e.g. I don't know exactly what you're referring to as "Hospitality" content.) Throw that in a codepen and then I'll have a look.

Comment: like this? http://codepen.io/alcoven/pen/ZYRBpv
I want each clicked color section to pull up one of those -expanded divs. so when color.1 is click 1-expanded is slid down, and color.2 2-expanded. ect

Comment: I've also added the corresponding name to each section in the html so you can see if the right one is being slideDown. Right now all 5 are coming up when 1/hospitality is clicked.

Comment: I tried changing your js and adding     'hospitality': ['.color-list .color.hospitality', '.greybg.tuckinfo'],
    'taverns': ['.color-list .color.taverns', '#wrapper .information'],
        'philanthropy': ['.color-list .color.philanthropy', '.greybg.tuckinfo']
 'consulting': ['.color-list .color.consulting', '.greybg.tuckinfo']
  };  But I still can't get the right results. :[

Comment: @Aaron So are you going to be able to change the classes assigned to each one of these in the actual markup? Or are you assigning these classes for the sake of example per my request?

Comment: I assigned them as you asked. Here's where I'm at. http://codepen.io/alcoven/pen/pvKzwd
only the last key element is working and all of the sections end up there.

Comment: @Aaron I am confused on what you're wanting to accomplish. When someone clicks on "Taverns" after an initial page load, what do you want to happen? Then, when someone clicks on X, X happens?

Comment: when someone clicks on taverns taverns-expanded slides down and all other X-expanded slideUp including .Information when Consulting is click consulting-expanded slidesDown.

Comment: @Aaron So when one of the five items (Hospitality "thru" Private Equity) is clicked, a child of the .tuckinfo element will be shown, and its siblings hidden. Is that a true statement?

Comment: @Aaron Is there a way for one to get back to the .information content after they've clicked one of "the five" ?

Comment: I was going to set up an X button to slide up all -expanded divs and slideDown information. As for you comment prior, exactly. this is basically a slider, using the color sections as buttons.

Comment: I see. Could you post a codepen with the markup as it will be in your output (since the assumption here is that you won't be able to modify it since it's in WP,) and I'll modify it from there. Your initial codepen appears to have changed.

Comment: codepen.io/alcoven/pen/pvKzwd Thank you! I've also added markup for the sections that will be revealed once the sub-nav a li's are clicked. this is a seperate function that I initially wasn't asking about. but Now am thinking maybe the code you're working on can be modular enough to work for those as well? Once the .color is clicked and the related -expanded section slidesDown there will be a nav in that section that will act as a slider as well. I'm working on a gif to show you.

Comment: http://imgur.com/nlA9O3M Here is the Gif for the action. each one of those .Color sections will have different sections slide down.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the target from `onousedown`:

```
window.onmousedown = function (event) {console.log(event.target);}
```

That should log your element

Comment: How do I strip all the code away and just take hospitality. than add that to a string like .hospitality-expanded?

Comment: Ah, sorry i misunderstood you the first time. Thought you were looking for a way to determine the element which was clicked.

`document.getElementByClass("color hospitality").className = "hospitality-expanded"`
 Am not using jQuery, so this is the raw DOM version